# Data studio bug in blending data sources with report URL parameters

Tags: url, parameters, looker-studio

Adding more visibility to an issue raised at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176032257

I created a report with a data source with a custom parameter.  I set the parameter value in the URL.

If I just show that data source and I show the parameter value as a calculated field, the parameter value is filled in.

If i use the parameter value in a table that blends this data source with another data source, the parameter value is not filled in, it's blank.

Therefore parameters are no good for use in blended data sources. This means we need to customize each datasource to contain all data needed and we need to create multiple parameters in order to filter each data source according to potentially the same parameter value (due to this issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180705297)

Additionally, if I create two custom data sources with dimensions of the same name which are populated by a parameter and I set the parameter value for one source in an input field, it updates the parameter value in both data sources.

Basically this all means I can't create a report with a custom URL parameter that will filter a blended data source, unless I add input boxes for the parameter, those boxes will be pre-filled from the URL parameter and then if I hit enter in those input boxes the blended data source will update correctly.

Has anyone else hit this issue and found any workarounds? Or is there someone at Google who can fix this?